# Save Contact ID From Sales Force Response Into Users Table Databasedotcom

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
***** RESPONSE: Net::HTTPOK -> {"status":"Success","primary_language":"notsure","PortalID":"1017","newContact":{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Contact/003f000000goEpIAAU"},"Primary_Language_Master__c":"notsure","npe01__Preferred_Email__c":"Personal","Country_of_Birth_Master__c":"argentina","npe01__HomeEmail__c":"john.smith1228+689@gmail.com","RecordTypeId":"012i0000000Ng8uAAC","Portal_ID__c":1017,"FirstName":"John","Id":"003f000000goEpIAAU","LastName":"Smith", "High_School_Graduation_Year__c":"2007"},"message":"Create was created successfully.","lastname":"Smith","high_school_graduation_year":2007,"firstname":"John","email":"john.smith1228+689@gmail.com","country_of_residence":"argentina","ContactID":"003f000000goEpIAAU"}
```

The above is a response getting returned after I use the databasedotcom gem to interact with salesforce. I am trying to collect the contactid into my users table after a successfuly response.

Below is the method that I am pushing with

```
  def salesforce_add_contact
    client = Databasedotcom::Client.new("config/databasedotcom.yml")
    client.authenticate(:username => "secret", :password => "secret" )

    params = { :PortalID => current_user.id.to_s,
               :firstname => current_user.first_name,
               :lastname => current_user.last_name,
               :email => current_user.email,
               :country_of_residence => current_user.country_of_residence,
               :primary_language => current_user.primary_language,
               :high_school_graduation_year => current_user.high_school_graduation_year}

    params = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(params)
    path = "/services/apexrest/v2/portalAccount"
    result = client.http_post(path, params)
    result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(result.body)

    puts result.body #just added

    if (response['status'] == "Success") #this didn't work
      current_user.sfdc_contact_id = response['ContactId']
      current_user.sfdc_contact_id.save
    end
  end
```

I am not totally understanding the syntax from the response and what kind of data structure is getting returned either....

I am trying to collect this `"ContactID":"003f000000goEpIAAU"`

***Updated***

I am getting `NoMethodError (undefined method`body' for #):`

when I do a `puts result.body` so I guess its not reading it correctly.

Comment: databasedotcom is no longer maintained, see its alternative restforce gem

Answer (score 0):

It looks you misnamed the variable that contains the decoded JSON response. You have:

```
result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(result.body)
```

Which should be:

```
response = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(result.body)
```

Comment: actually I notice that I a bit later, but changing it back to `result` isn't doing the trick. It used to be `result` but I figured ruby may have something like `response`